# Pandas Chunksize iterator

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 1GB, 70M row file which anytime I load it all it runs out of memory. I have read in 1000 rows and been able to prototype what I'd like it to do.

My problem is not knowing how to get the next 1000 rows and apply my logic and then continue to run through my file until it finishes the last rows. I've read about chunksizing, although I can't figure out how to continue the iteration of the chunksizing.

Ideally, it would flow like such:

1)read in first 1000 rows
2)filter data based on criteria
3)write to csv
4)repeat until no more rows

Here's what i have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_table('datafile.txt',sep='\t',chunksize=1000, iterator=True)
data=data[data['visits']>10]
with open('data.csv', 'a') as f:
    data.to_csv(f,sep = ',', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: How much memory does your computer have?
How many columns does the text file have?
You could also loop through the entire file without pandas, if you truly only want to filter on some criteria

Comment: 4gb worth or RAM. I know, time to update.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have some problems with your logic, we want to loop over each chunk in the data, not the data itself.

The 'chunksize' argument gives us a 'textreader object' that we can iterate over.

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_table('datafile.txt',sep='\t',chunksize=1000)

for chunk in data:
    chunk = chunk[chunk['visits']>10]
    chunk.to_csv('data.csv', index = False, header = False)
```

You will need to think about how to handle your header!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm still so confused with parameter `iterator` in `read_csv()`. Does setting the  `iterator=True` make any difference ? Thanks

Comment: yes - if you have `iterator = False` (the default), you get a dataframe out, with it set to true, you get an object that you can get each `chunk size` of the data frame out of.

Answer (score 3):

When you pass a `chunksize` or `iterator=True`, `pd.read_table` returns a TextFileReader that you can iterate over or call `get_chunk` on. So you need to iterate or call `get_chunk` on `data`.

So proper handling of your entire file might look something like

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_table('datafile.txt',sep='\t',chunksize=1000, iterator=True)

with open('data.csv', 'a') as f:
    for chunk in data:
        chunk[chunk.visits > 10].to_csv(f, sep=',', index=False, header=False)
```